# Full-text searth JSON-string

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, sphinx

I have a question: in my DB i have a table, who has a field with JSON-string, like:
field "description"

```js
{
solve_what: "Add project problem",
solve_where: "In project CRUD",
shortname: "Add error"
}
```

How can i full-text search for this string? For example, I need to find all records, who has "*project*" in description.solve_what. In my sphinx.conf i have

```
sql_attr_json = description
```

P.S.Mb i can do this with elasticSearch?

Comment: Elasticsearch is definitely a good candidate for solving full text search challenges. Not knowing much about your specific use cases, I can't advise much further, but since you have JSON data handy, you might want to investigate this further and come back with more specific questions about issues you encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just answered a very similar questio here:
http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=13861

> Note there is no support for extracting them as FIELDs at this time -
>   so cant 'full-text' search the text within the json elements.
>
> (To do that would have to use mysql string manipulation functions to
>   create a new column to index as a normal field. Something like:
>
> SELECT id, SUBSTR(json_column,
>       LOCATE('"tag":"', json_column)+7,
>       LOCATE('"', json_column, LOCATE('"tag":"', json_column)+7)-LOCATE('"tag":"',
>       json_column)-7 ) AS tag, ...
>
> is messy but should work... )

The code is untested.